# use SqlConnection, but can not find the SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database

My database layout looks like this:

```
-App_Data
    -Database.mdf
        -Database_log.ldf
```

and this is my code:

```
            string strConn = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Database;Integrated Security=True;";
        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
        myConn.Open();
        String strSQL = "INSERT INTO dbo.member (Id, Password, Name, Jobtitle,level,phone) VALUES ('a01', '123', 'bobo', 'Tester','1','010919')";
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, myConn);
        myConn.Close();
```

When I test in browser, however, it sends an error message and stops in this code `"myConn.Open();"can't find server`

Why is this happening?

Comment: Shouldn't you specify somehwere which mdf file to use?

Comment: Forgot to mention server, user and pass. Here's an example: conn.ConnectionString =
"Data Source=ServerName;" +
"Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;" +
"User id=UserName;" +
"Password=Secret;";
conn.Open();

Comment: i use windows verification,seem only sql verification need id and password?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 string strConn = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Database;Integrated Security=True;";
```

to

```
 string strConn = @"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Database;Integrated Security=True";
```

Comment: i've removed ';' at the end of Integrated Security =true check the full line

Comment: and for me the name SQLExpress causes problems if i change the case

Comment: @user5509470 are you sure the server is running when you execute ?

Comment: but i run web in localhost ,how to check the server is enabled?

Comment: go to services on windows  check if the service of SQLExpress is still running

Comment: i know can disconnect,and database icon will show the"x"make

Comment: you mean ctrl+alt+delete?

Comment: go to System32 folder and open "services.msc"

Comment: oh i check ,and i find the program name "sqlserver.exe",SQL Server Windows NT - 64 Bit

Comment: i go to there and see the name"SQL Server VSS Writer" state is enabled

Comment: right click on the sqlexpress service and start it if it's not

Comment: i right click,but the start can't click,so i click the restart and try ,but still error

Comment: replace Data Source=.\SQLExpress;
with Data Source=(local);

Answer (score 0):

> Attach a database file, located in the data directory, on connect to a
>   local SQL Server Express instance
>
> ```
> Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|dbfilename.mdf;Database=dbname;
> Trusted_Connection=Yes;
> ```

so your connection string should be similar to below, replace database name corectly

```
string strConn =@"Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;Database=dbname; Trusted_Connection=Yes;";

using (SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(strConn))
{
  string strSQL = "INSERT INTO dbo.member (Id, Password, Name, Jobtitle,level,phone) VALUES ('a01', '123', 'bobo', 'Tester','1','010919')";
  myConn.Open();
  using(SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, myConn))
  {
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); // you haven't execute the insert 
  }
}
```

Comment: i copy the code and replace the database name , but it not work,still stop on"myConn.Open();"

Comment: what is your database name? also what is the error you received now?

Comment: i use default name,and the error message is this"provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26"

Comment: unless the database name is not show in project layout ?i open the table"mamber",but title show "dbo.member"